# NTFS ESATA disk needs to be "partprobe"d on every reboot

Tags: mount

I have an ESATA disk with NTFS that works fine on Windows. It is recognized as the `/dev/sde` device, but no partition is recognized (no `/dev/sde1`) unless `partprobe` is run. After this, device `/dev/sde1` appears and can be mounted with `mount`. `fdisk` does show `/dev/sde1` even before `partprobe` is run.

What could be the reason for this? Are there any workarounds, other than creating a script that runs at startup that `partprobe`'s and mounts it?

Thanks

**EDIT (extra info)**

`/dev/sde1` doesn't exist until I partprobe, so I can't even try to mount it. If I try I get "device does not exist". If I try to mount "sde", I get the error "unknown filesystem type 'isw_raid_member'

This is what I get from `parted`

```
Model: ATA WDC WD5000AAKS-0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sde: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  500GB  500GB  primary  ntfs         boot
```

If there's any additional relevant information to give, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I would run a `chkdisk` on Windows on this HDD prior to trying to mount it on Linux. It sounds like the partition table, or the partition(s), were not properly unmounted at some point in this HDD's life.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried it and but found no errors, and the issue remains

Comment: @Rojo - can you show us the error?

Comment: Sure. I just edited the question

Comment: @Rojo - can you try running `ntfsfix` against this device? See `man ntfsfix` for info.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I ran it. Everything ok, and booted into Windows afterwards. Nothing is changed

Comment: @Rojo - the HDD, `/dev/sde` doesn't show up in `dmesg` when the system boots either?

Comment: `dmesg | grep /dev/sde` doesn't show results but this is not right after booting. I'll try it as soon as I can (in about 12-16hs) and post back

Comment: No output, no messages